# Allow one VPC and deny others in a VPC Service Perimeter GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, vpc, google-cloud-iam

I have created a VPC Service Perimeter for a project in GCP and added Google Cloud Storage to it.

Is there a way in GCP to allow access to Google Cloud Storage API (via gsutil or any other means) only to the VMs or resources in a particular VPC?

If I have three VPCs (***vpc-a***, ***vpc-b*** and ***vpc-c***), I want only the instances in ***vpc-a*** to access the Cloud Storage buckets and VPC Service Perimeter to deny access to resources from ***vpc-b*** and ***vpc-c***.

All my instances will be private (no public IP address) and consider the VPCs and VMs to be in one project (added in VPC Service Perimeter). How to achieve the above setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Access Context Manager, GCP Service Controls or Google Cloud Storage.

VPC Service Controls are project based and are not VPC based. VPC Service Controls islands a project's resources. You would need the ability to remove certain resources (VPC) from accessing this island.

Access Context Manager does not define a condition for VPC subnets or private IP CIDR blocks.

VPC Service Controls does not block resources inside the project.

There is no supported method to block one VPC and allow another where both VPCs are inside the same project.

Comment: I am actually talking about the VPC service perimeter not particularly GCP Cloud Storage. VPC service perimeter give additional security to GCP services. How to leverage that to allow access to a service from one VPC and deny for others?

Comment: I have rewritten my answer based upon your comment.

Comment: That makes the use of VPC service controls clear. Thanks. What is the preferred way to make sure a GCP Storage Bucket is only accessible from a specific VPC, user or service account?

Comment: Please close the question. Besides using IAM and ACLs for users and VPC Service Controls for projects. nothing else exists (at this date) for GCP. I use IAM and ACLs to control Cloud Storage.

Comment: Is it possible to create two projects, keep cloud storage in one project (and protect the project as well as Cloud Storage service inside a VPC service perimeter) and 3 VPCs in another project and allow only one of the three VPCs to access the Cloud storage in another project protected by a Service perimeter?